# What is difference between class variable and variable defined on class level

Tags: ruby, oop

What is the difference between class variable and variable defined on the class level?

say, bar is defined with `@@` which means it's a class variable and will be accessible within all methods in class.

```
class Foo
  @@bar = 'bar'
end
```

so does `bar` without `@@`, so what is the difference..?

```
class Foo
  bar = 'bar'
end
```

Comment: The difference is that your statement is wrong. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with your second option, `bar` is a local variable which gets out of scope when reaching the `end`. As such, it won't be accessible to any methods (class methods nor instance methods) of the class.

With that being said, in Ruby, there are class variables (`@@bar` which are shared between all child classes and their instances and instance variables (`@bar`) Since classes are also just objects in Ruby, you can also define an instance variable on class level (or more correctly: on the singleton class of your class). This can work like this:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    @bar
  end

  def self.bar=(value)
    @bar = value
  end
end
```

Compared to class variables, these instance variables on the singleton class are not accessible on `Foo` instances nor on child classes of `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

The `@@bar` will return the same variable to all instances of the class, not just the same variable to all methods in the class.

The way I think of class variables (@@variables) is as namespaced global variables. Their usage is just about as frowned upon as using global variables, but not quite since you are limiting the scope to within the code defined in your class.

Generally they would be used to track some kind of state across your application.

Let's say you had an object that needed to be able to identify its most recently instantiated sibling object.
One way to do that would be via a global variable:

```
class MyThing
  def initialize
    $latest_thing = self
  end

  def latest
    $latest_thing
  end
end

thing1 = MyThing.new
thing1.latest         # => thing1
thing2 = MyThing.new
thing1.latest         # => thing2
thing2.latest         # => thing2
```

Now, that uses a global variable which is generally perceived as bad practice, one of the reasons being for pollution of the global namespace and risk of naming collision and/or someone else changing it.

If you are dealing with a situation like this where you need this shared state between instances, but no one outside needs to know about it, then you can use the class variable exactly like a global:

```
class MyThing
  def initialize
    @@latest_thing = self
  end

  def latest
    @@latest_thing
  end
end

thing1 = MyThing.new
thing1.latest         # => thing1
thing2 = MyThing.new
thing1.latest         # => thing2
thing2.latest         # => thing2
```

That's just generally cleaner/safer/better encapsulated, since any 3rd party code can not simply do `@@latest_thing = :something_else` the way that they could do had a global been used.

Hope that helps. I think class variables are rarely used or encouraged in the wild, but on the rare occasion I've needed to use one it was for things like this.

Comment: Globals are extremely bad in practice, they're far too broad in scope, but class-level variables are a close second. 99% of the time what you need is a class-level method that can intermediate this for you, like `self.class.latest_thing = self` where that's a method. The class itself is then free to interpret that however it sees fit.